# Is there any reason to use a regular lock over a recursive lock?

Tags: multithreading, locking

When a thread tries to acquire a recursive lock again that it already holds, `rlock.acquire()` allows the thread to continue and does not block the thread.

When, on the other hand, a thread tries to acquire a regular lock that it already holds then the thread is then just stuck in a deadlock.

The second case seems to me like just a source of trouble since it is a situation that cannot be easily recovered from (the thread is just stuck on the `lock.acquire()`) and that is kinda hard to diagnose (no exception is thrown or anything, the thread is just stuck).

I have seen it quite a few times so far that someone actually wanted to use an `RLock` but instead used a regular `Lock` and spent a while debugging that problem. While on the other hand I never encountered a situation where a `Lock` would have actually been better. It could arguably be used when there is a really critical part of the code that should not be accessed by the same thread twice at a time, but for that to happen the code inside that critical part would need to call itself, which would be something that should be quite obvious to the programmer.

So, is there any case where an `Lock` is better than an `RLock`? And if not, should language designers keep providing the regular `Lock` at all?

Comment: I think your talking about Python locks here is this the case?  If it is can you edit the question and add the appropriate Python tag.

Comment: *When a thread tries to acquire a recursive lock again that it already holds, `rlock.acquire()` allows the thread to continue and does not block the thread.*  And that can be wrong if the underlying algorithm depends on the lock not being acquired multiple times, even by the same thread.  Reacquiring the lock may not be safe and might result in corrupted data.

Comment: @Jackson I am talking about locks without a specific language in mind. Similar things apply to locks in e.g. Java. There it's called `ReentrantLock`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are Python lock objects the documentation shows that they are quite different.  The main differences between the two are:

- A Lock can be released by **any** thread not just the thread that acquired it
- An Rlock can only be released by the thread that acquired
- An Rlock must be released once for each time it is acquired by the thread

So a Lock allows you to build threading schemes where the lock is acquired in one thread but released in another thread.  One example might be a pipeline of threads processing a piece of work, the work distributer gets the lock but it's released by the last thread in the pipeline.